# UITableView all registered classes / nibs

Tags: ios, uitableview

How can I view already registered classes and/or nibs and their cell identifier?

I would like to see which have been automatically registered within the xib (if that's how it's done), but also being able to see any manually registered would be great too.

Comment: What are you going to do with this information? Is it just for interest / debugging?

Comment: @Wain Just for debugging. I needed this when I had issues with verifying I setup my Storyboard correctly.

Comment: it is also used in unit testing if u want to test if a cell is registered or not in a certain tableview

Answer (score 17, accepted):

UITableView stores information about registered cell classes and nibs in separate dictionaries, which you can get using KVC and private property keys:

```
NSDictionary *registeredCellClasses = [tableView valueForKey:@"_cellClassDict"];
NSDictionary *registeredNibs = [tableView valueForKey:@"_nibMap"];
```

Each dictionary stores registered cell reuse identifiers as keys and class names/Nib objects as values.

Comment: any idea for collectionview?

Answer (score 8):

**Swift**

```
let registeredCellClasses = tableView.value(forKey: "_cellClassDict") as? [String:Any]
let registeredNibs = tableView.value(forKey: "_nibMap") as? [String:UINib]
```

Answer (score 4):

```
extension UITableView {

var registeredNibs: [String: UINib] {
    let dict = value(forKey: "_nibMap") as? [String: UINib]
    return dict ?? [:]
}

var registeredClasses: [String: Any] {
    let dict = value(forKey: "_cellClassDict") as? [String: Any]
    return dict ?? [:]
}
}
```

Comment: @MichaelOzeryansky: I think he just want to show another approach

Answer (score 1):

### Details

- Xcode 12.3 (12C33)
- Swift 5.3

### Problem

Usage of the `_nibMap` and `_cellClassDict` may be not safe. Apple has not direct API to get registered cells. So, solutions based on `_nibMap` and `_cellClassDict` looks like hacks. And we can not predict, will Apple change this API or not. I suggest to make own `TableView` and implement storing logic there.

### Solution

```
class TableView: UITableView {
    private (set) lazy var registeredCellIdentifiers = Set<String>()
    
    func register(nib: UINib?, forCellReuseIdentifier identifier: String) {
        super.register(nib, forCellReuseIdentifier: identifier)
        registeredCellIdentifiers.insert(identifier)
    }
    
    func register(nib: UINib?, forHeaderFooterViewReuseIdentifier identifier: String) {
        super.register(nib, forHeaderFooterViewReuseIdentifier: identifier)
        registeredCellIdentifiers.insert(identifier)
    }
    
    func register(cellClass: AnyClass?, forCellReuseIdentifier identifier: String) {
        super.register(cellClass, forCellReuseIdentifier: identifier)
        registeredCellIdentifiers.insert(identifier)
    }
    
    func register(aClass: AnyClass?, forHeaderFooterViewReuseIdentifier identifier: String) {
        super.register(aClass, forHeaderFooterViewReuseIdentifier: identifier)
        registeredCellIdentifiers.insert(identifier)
    }

    @available(*, deprecated, message: "use register(nib: UINib?, forCellReuseIdentifier identifier: String) instead")
    override func register(_ nib: UINib?, forCellReuseIdentifier identifier: String) {}
    
    @available(*, deprecated, message: "use register(nib: UINib?, forCellReuseIdentifier identifier: String) instead")
    override func register(_ nib: UINib?, forCellReuseIdentifier identifier: String) {}
    
    @available(*, deprecated, message: "use register(nib: UINib?, forHeaderFooterViewReuseIdentifier identifier: String) instead")
    override func register(_ nib: UINib?, forHeaderFooterViewReuseIdentifier identifier: String) { }

    @available(*, deprecated, message: "ude register(cellClass: AnyClass?, forCellReuseIdentifier identifier: String) instead")
    override func register(_ cellClass: AnyClass?, forCellReuseIdentifier identifier: String) {}

    @available(*, deprecated, message: "use register(aClass: AnyClass?, forHeaderFooterViewReuseIdentifier identifier: String) instead")
    override func register(_ aClass: AnyClass?, forHeaderFooterViewReuseIdentifier identifier: String) {}
}
```

### Full Sample

> Do not forget to paste here code defined above

```
// MARK: - Auto Generated identifiers

protocol Identifiable: class {
    static var identifier: String { get }
}

extension Identifiable {
    static var identifier: String { "\(self)" }
}

// MARK: - Define Cells

class TableViewCell: UITableViewCell, Identifiable {
    var mainBackgroundColor: UIColor { .white }
    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        backgroundColor = mainBackgroundColor
    }

    @available(*, deprecated, message: "")
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) { fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented") }
}

class GreenCell: TableViewCell {
    override var mainBackgroundColor: UIColor { .green }
}

class OrangeCell: TableViewCell {
    override var mainBackgroundColor: UIColor { .orange }
}

// MARK: ViewController

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        let tableView = TableView()
        view.addSubview(tableView)
        tableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        tableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor).isActive = true
        tableView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor).isActive = true
        tableView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        tableView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor).isActive = true
        
        tableView.register(cellClass: GreenCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: GreenCell.identifier)
        tableView.register(cellClass: OrangeCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: OrangeCell.identifier)
        tableView.dataSource = self
        
        print(tableView.registeredCellIdentifiers)
    }
}

// MARK: - UITableViewDataSource

extension ViewController: UITableViewDataSource {
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int { 1 }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int { 10 }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let identifier = (indexPath.row % 2) == 0 ? GreenCell.identifier :  OrangeCell.identifier
        return tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: identifier) ?? UITableViewCell()
    }
}
```

Comment: I know it's a more a production ready solution, but originally I was looking just for debugging purposes. Interesting template you have there.